# Java parse XML with question mark tag?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jaxb

i want to ask something.

I found an XML like this one.

```html
<row><?TAGS?><?TAG 024?><?END-TAGS?>
<entry colname="COL1">1</entry>
<entry colname="COL2">2</entry>
<entry colname="COL3">3</entry>
</row>
```

Do you know how to get all TAG values inside `<?TAGS?>`?
What's that XML bracket `<??>` for?

For now I am using JAXB annotations and cannot get those tags.

Thanks :)

Comment: These `<?...?>` things are are [XML processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction). As far as I know JAXB doesn't support them.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch so i cannot take that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<?anything?>` parts are [XML processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction).

**Unmarshalling:**

As far as I know JAXB alone doesn't support processing instructions
during unmarshalling. They are just ignored.

However, according to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056085/reading-the-custom-xml-processing-instruction-through-jaxb-unmarshelling)
you can get them by using JAXB together with either StAX or SAX.

**Marshalling:**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153219/making-jaxb-generate-an-xml-processing-instruction/19033296#19033296)
you can tell the JAXB marshaller to insert your XML processing instructions
at the beginning of the XML output. Like this:

```
Marshaller marshaller = ...;
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders",
        "<?TAGS?><?TAG 024?><?END-TAGS?>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Another option is to use XSLT prior to unmarshalling. You can quite easily convert processing intructions into elements with XSLT.